# MacBook Pro won’t stay on Wi-Fi at home but is fine at work. Why?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, ventura, modem

My Wi-Fi connection randomly drops and comes back if I toggle off and on. It’s been going on for a month.

If I take it to work, it stays on that Wi-Fi network all day without dropping once. I’ve tested it on several days.

I took it to Apple and they said the Wi-Fi card is fine, likely xfinity’s issue. But all other devices on my network stay connected with no problems.

Xfinity said my connection is great and the modem is fine.

I’m at a loss.

MacBook Pro 2017
Ventura 13.4.1(c)

Comment: I am willing to be the issue is the WiFi radio (low quality) in the Xfiniti modem.  I suggest getting a better WiFi router/access point like a Netgear or Ubiquiti.  Besides, you want to be in control of the firewall between you and the Internet, not have a 3rd party handle it.

Comment: If you haven't already, tear down the home WiFi network on your Mac and rebuild it. Do you have other devices which use your home WiFi with no issues? (Other computers, iPhone/iPad.)

Comment: All my other devices are totally fine: iPad sitting right next to the MacBook is quite happy, as are the Alexa, HomePod and all my kids’ gaming devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you hold Option, and click on the WiFi menulet, you get some information about RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indicator) and noise, which may be useful.

[image]

There are also various utility apps which can show you the signal-to-noise ratio, and other characteristics of WiFI signals. Some will even map out the hotspots in your house.